# SAWarning error "SELECT statement has a cartesian product" when trying to append to bridging table in many to many relationship

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to have two tables.  One of ideas and another of tags.  This relationship should be many to many.

I've created a bridging table:

```
tag_idea = db.Table('tag_idea', 
        db.Column('idea_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('idea.id')),
        db.Column('ideatag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('idea_tag.id'))
        )
```

These are my two models:

```
class Idea(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    idea_name = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False)
    idea = db.Column(db.String(5000), nullable=False)
    idea_owner = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    idea_category = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'), nullable=False)
    tags = db.relationship('IdeaTag', secondary=tag_idea, backref='ideas',
            primaryjoin=tag_idea.c.idea_id==id,
            secondaryjoin=tag_idea.c.ideatag_id==id)


class IdeaTag(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag = db.Column(db.String(25), nullable=False)
    tag_owner = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
```

so to test this I loaded a test idea into `test` and a test tag into `testtag`

to add to the bridging table I figured I should be able to use:

`idea.tags.append(testtag)`

But I get the following error:

`SAWarning: SELECT statement has a cartesian product between FROM element(s) "tag_idea", "idea" and FROM element "idea_tag".  Apply join condition(s) between each element to resolve.`

On the surface, I'm not actually entering a SELECT statement so I don't know how to apply a join in the SELECT statement.  How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by setting my backref parameter to this:

`backref=db.backref('ideas', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic,`